# Bash: Created a ~ (Tilde) in a directory by accident

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I'm a beginner to using bash on OSX, and I somehow created a `~` dir in a project subfolder. (It appears as a directory, rather than  a symlink.)

Is there a safe way to get rid of this `~` directory instance without bash expanding the tilde wiping my local user directory?

This is a really goofy question, but it would be a huge help to figure out how to deal with this.

Comment: `rm -r '~'` should do. Or `rm -r './~'`. If you want to be _really_ safe, run `rm` with the `-i` option (interactive) that will prompt you before erasing anything. E.g., `rm -ri './~'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Use:

`rm -rf \~`

(that is: tilda prefixed with a backslash)

But, to be really sure, place yourself in the parent directory of the tilda and type:

`rm -rf ./\~`

That way, you really specify: the tilde in the *current directory*

Comment: Instead of `\~` you can also say `'~'` (i.e., with single quotes).

Comment: @bitmask: you are right

Comment: I, too, had accidentally created a tilde (`~`) within a project directory on Mac. I'm not sure how I did (when using mongodump). I was very nervous about deleting it because I didn't want to delete all of the folders that it contains. Thanks for your answer. `rm -rf ./\~` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

`rmdir` will only remove empty directories. That way you are really sure you won't lose anything important.

Comment: Unless you pass `-r`, so will `rm`.

Comment: `rm` will not remove a directory at all without `-r`, which makes it a bad choice for this task.

Comment: I cannot help but noticing that I was talking utter nonsense before and that you are absolutely right. Sorry for that (the nonsense talking, not the noticing, that is).